# MonoTouch.Dialog how to get data from radiogroup

Tags: delegates, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm beginner in monotouch.dialog.
i am trying to get a value from radiogroup with a override radioelement with caption and value as a classic dropdownlist!

but the problem is to detect the event OnSelect

CODE OF MYRADIOELEMENT

```
public class MyRadioElement : RadioElement
  {

    private string Caption{get; set;}
    private int ID{get; set;}

        public MyRadioElement(string caption, int id, NSAction selected): base(caption, id)
        {
            Caption = caption;
            ID = id;

            OnSelected += selected;
        }

    public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
    {
        base.Selected (dvc, tableView, path);
        var selected = OnSelected;
        if (selected != null)
            selected ();
    }

    public event NSAction OnSelected;

}
```

CODE OF ROOTELEMENT

```
var rootSex = new RootElement ("SEX",
sexUser = new RadioGroup ("", -1)){new Section ("INSERT SEX"){
from n in Def.Get_Sexes()
select (Element) new MyRadioElement (n.Descr, n.ID, ????delegate????? )}
};
```

I would use the delegate to invoke the event of selection, but it gives me a conversion error...

Why???
thanks

Answer (score 4):

This one should work

```
class MyRadioElement: RadioElement
{
    private Action<MyRadioElement> selected;

    public MyRadioElement(string caption, int id,  Action<MyRadioElement> selected): base(caption, id)
    {
        this.selected = selected;
    }


    public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
    {
        base.Selected (dvc, tableView, path);

        if (this.selected != null)  
                    this.selected(this);

    }
}
```

And you would then create the element as

```
new MyRadioElement("Caption", 2, MyMethod)
```

MyMethod would look like

```
private void MyMethod(MyRadioElement e)
{

}
```

Comment: Tanks Jamie
but I need the selected object, with 2 property: Caption and ID


    select (Element) new MyRadioElement (n.Descr, n.ID, ()=>                                         {  
                            })

Comment: I've not got access to mt dialog just now, but does RadioGroup.Selected let you access those properties? You can cast that to your own type if required.

Comment: Sorry but I didt understand how can I do, could you do me an example?

Comment: I've updated my example.  Example is in the OptionSelected() method.  Note the cast to MyRAdioElement to access ID.  RadioElement already has a caption property

Comment: Thank you, but Selected is Int not Radioelement....
and for this, have convert error

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was trying to answer from memory.  I've update now with something I have compiled and ran in MT

Comment: Thanks Jamie!
Its ok!

PS. "Action<LayoutRadioElement>" not correct --> Action<MyRadioElement"> 

ciao!